# Conda / pycups / py37: Symbol not found: _libiconv on macOS mojave

Tags: macos, anaconda, conda, python-3.7, pycups

i am struggling to get `pycups` to work in a `conda` environment.

I get `Symbol not found: _libiconv`.

I'm running on macOS Mojave.

I assume it is a path problem because on the same machine it works fine installed in an environment created using python3: `python3 -m venv myenv`

but with conda, no such luck:

```
conda create myenv python=3.7
conda activate myenv
pip install pycups
```

```
python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 16:54:48)
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import cups

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cups.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _libiconv
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cups.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
 in /anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cups.cpython-37m-darwin.so
```

Comment: Did you try  "conda install pycups"?

Comment: there is a channel ``avanderm``, but this is old and has a package for linux/py35 only. On the mac ``conda install -c avanderm pycups`` returns ``PackagesNotFoundError``. Thanks!